# Scaling CALayer without altering sublayer transform

Tags: ios, calayer, quartz-graphics, cabasicanimation, caanimation

I have a CALayer called photoLayer which has a sublayer called imageLayer whose contents is a CGImageRef. The user can select a crop rect in the image & also zoom with fingers using Pan/Zoom gestures (this selection is part of another UI using UIScrollView). To display the image in imageLayer with chosen crop rect and zoom value, I apply a scale transform to imageLayer to chosen zoom value. I also adjust imageLayer's position property to match the top left corner in the image crop rectangle selected using pan/zoom. This way I am able to display imageLayer with cropped/zoomed image correctly.

But now I also need to scale up photoLayer (i.e. parent layer of imageLayer) around the centre and when I apply the transform.scale animation to photoLayer, the imageLayer does not scale along the centre. I was expecting imageLayer to be unaffected by super layer's scale animation but that's not the case. What am I doing wrong ? Here is how I scale photoLayer :

```
            CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
            [scale setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
            [scale setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
            scale.beginTime = startTime;
            scale.duration = 1.f;
            [scale setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
            [scale setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

            [photoLayer addAnimation:scale forKey:@"scaleUp"];
```

I really need imageLayer to follow photoLayer's scale animation around centre.

Comment: I don't quite understand what photoLayer is for. Why do you need it?

Comment: @AnnaDickinson Thanks for the response. What I am trying to do is to setup a bunch of CALayers and animate them to generate slideshow of images with transitions. This setup allows for realtime preview as well as offline rendering to generate a movie file for the slideshow. Separating imageLayer from photoLayer was very much essential due to transitions requirements. As an example, if I have a fadein/fadeout transition through black transition, I can implement it by turning photoLayer background colour to black and have an opacity animation applied to imageLayer.

Comment: Sounds like you just have a geometry problem.  Applying successive transforms to things sometimes yields counterintuitive results. All you can do is draw it on paper and go through the math!

Comment: Ok I solved the problem, the fix was simple. Set photoLayer.masksToBounds = YES and the transforms are now all around centre !

Comment: that's exactly the animation I needed for my layer (i have no sublayers). thanks for the code (to copypaste).